# find the begin and end index of shortest substring in a string that match another pattern

Tags: python, c++, string, algorithm

Given two strings `text` and `pattern`, find the begin and end index of the shortest substring in `text` that matches `pattern`, this means that all characters in `pattern` appear in the same order in both the substring and `pattern`, but there maybe other characters in between these characters.

If you can find such substring from `text`, print its begin and end index, else print -1, -1. If there are multiple shortest matching substring, return the indexes of substring with smallest begin index.

Sample input:

```
axxxbcaxbcaxxbc abc

abcd x

axxxbaxbab ab
```

Sample output:

```
6 9

-1 -1

8 9
```

Does anyone have some good algorithm to solve this problem without employing the 
builtin support for regular expression in C++ or Python

Comment: having `string = 'xxxxxxxxxx'` and `pattern = 'x'` is `0 1` a valid answer ?

Comment: You can return the index of first found substring, so the output can be 0, 0.

Comment: Then why not just try finding first occurence of your pattern in the string ? Then add the length of the pattern to find the end index

Comment: because characters in pattern do not need to be next to each other in the found substring, read carefully about the problem statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python

```
def shortest_match(text, pattern):

    stack = [] # to store matches

    for i in range(len(text) - len(pattern) + 1):
        # if we match the firts character of pattern in
        # text then we start to search for the rest of it
        if pattern[0] == text[i]:
            j = 1 # pattern[0] already match, let's check from 1 onwards
            k = i + 1 # text[i] == pattern[0], let's check from text[i+1] onwards
            # while pattern[j] could match text[i]
            while j < len(pattern) and k < len(text):
                if pattern[j] == text[k]:
                    j += 1 # pattern[j] matched. Let's move to the next character
                k += 1
            if j == len(pattern): # if the match was found add it to the stack
                stack.append((i, k-1))
            else: # otherwise break the loop (we won't find any other match)
                break
    if not stack: # no match found
        return (-1, -1)
    lengths = [y - x for x, y in stack] # list of matches lengths
    return stack[lengths.index(min(lengths))] # return the shortest
```

---

### C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct match_pair
{
    int start;
    int end;
    int length;
};

void
print_match (match_pair m)
{
    cout << "(" << m.start << ", " << m.end << ")";
}

match_pair 
shortest_match (char * text, char * pattern) 
{

  vector <match_pair> stack; // to store matches

  for (int i = 0; strlen(text) - strlen(pattern) + 1; ++i)
  {
    // if we match the firts character of pattern in
    // text then we start to search for the rest of it
    if (pattern[0] == text[i])
    {
        int j = 1; // pattern[0] already match, let's check from 1 onwards
        int k = i + 1; // text[i] == pattern[0], let's check from text[i+1] onwards
        // while pattern[j] could match text[i]
        while (j < strlen(pattern) && k < strlen(text))
        {
            if (pattern[j] == text[k])
            {
                ++j; // pattern[j] matched. Let's move to the next character
            }
            ++k;
        }
        if (j == strlen(pattern)) // if the match was found add it to the stack
        {
            match_pair current_match;
            current_match.start = i;
            current_match.end = k - 1;
            current_match.length = current_match.end - current_match.start;
            stack.push_back(current_match);
        } else // otherwise break the loop (we won't find any other match)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
  }

  match_pair shortest;
  if (stack.empty()) // no match, return (-1, -1)
  {
    shortest.start = -1;
    shortest.end = -1;
    shortest.length = 0;
    return shortest;
  }
  // search for shortest match
  shortest.start = stack[0].start;
    shortest.end = stack[0].end;
    shortest.length = stack[0].length;
  for (int i = 1; i < stack.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (stack[i].length < shortest.length)
    {
        shortest.start = stack[i].start;
        shortest.end = stack[i].end;
        shortest.length = stack[i].length;
    }
  }

  return shortest;

}

// override << for printing match_pair
std::ostream& 
operator<< (std::ostream& os, const match_pair& m)
{
    return os << "(" <<  m.start << ", " << m.end << ")"; 
}

int
main () 
{
  char text[] = "axxxbcaxbcaxxbc";
  char pattern[] = "abc";

  cout << shortest_match(text, pattern);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it fork for pattern "abaa" and string "ababa"?

Comment: @algrid In my understanding of the question such pair shouldn't match, so I'd say it works.

Comment: Well, in my understanding that *should* match :)

Comment: @algrid I think you're right... I edited the answer. KMP doesn't help anymore, though.

Comment: "abaa" should definitely match "ababa"

Comment: @jdhao and in fact it does now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the text's chars and find the first character of the pattern in the text. If you find it, search for an occurence of the second character of your pattern in the remaining text and repeat the operation over all chars in pattern, skipping unwanted chars in text. When done, start again with next occurence of pattern's first char in text.

Maybe something more visual with the `abc` pattern :

```
axxxbcaxbcaxxbc
[axxx|b|c] -> 6 chars
[ax|b|c] -> 4 chars
[axx|b|c] -> 5 chars
```

Or

```
 aababaccccccc
[aa|baba|c] -> 6 chars
[a|baba|c] -> 5 chars
[a|ba|c] -> 4 chars
[accccccc] -> -1 chars as the substring does not match the pattern
```

EDIT: You should try to implement this algorithm starting at the end of your text as it's the place the substring you are looking for will most likely be.